# How can I find all ways of pairing elements between two lists of equal length?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Suppose I have two input lists like:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

I want to get a list of lists of tuples, of all the potential combinations between the two - i.e., of ways to pair all the elements up. Thus, the result should be like:

```
[
    [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)],
    [(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5)],
    [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)],
    [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)],
    [(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)],
    [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
]
```

That is: the first list shows the `1` being paired with the `4`, the `2` with the `5`, and the `3` with the `6`. There are 6 lists, corresponding to all the ways that the elements from `list1` could be associated with the elements of `list2`.

I think the `itertools` standard library should be helpful here, but I couldn't figure out a solution. I got this far:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [5, 6, 7]
print(list(itertools.product(list1, list2)))
```

but the result is:

```
[(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)]
```

It shows every possible pairing of an element from `list1` with an element of `list2`, but not the possible resulting lists composed from these pairing.

How can I fix the code?

Comment: `[[[1,3], [2,4]], [[1,4], [2,3]]]` Why a list of lists of lists? Why not a list of lists? What are the criteria? When does an item go in the 1st or 2nd list? I would expect the expected result to be `[[1,3], [2,4], [1,4], [2,3]]`

Comment: That's pretty much what itertools.product is giving me (just a list of tuples instead of a list of list).  I'm not trying to find all the possible combinations of items on both lists, but all the possible lists I can produce by merging the two.

I'm going to add another edit to try to explain in more plain English instead of just expected code output.

Comment: Do you want all the possible interweavings of the two lists? Like what would happen during shuffling of cards. So the example `[1, 2], [3, 4]` would result in the sequences or so: `1 2 3 4 / 1 3 2 4 / 1 3 4 2 / 3 4 1 2 / 3 1 4 2 / 3 1 2 4`.

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: Padraic, not necessarily. I can always do sorts on the output list if needed.

Comment: Dan, close to it, but there's no assumption that the same values - or even types - are in both lists.  (In other words, this should work even if the lists are [1,2] and ['d', 'e'].

Comment: If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306231/how-to-calculate-all-interleavings-of-two-lists the definition `slot_combinations` computes that result.

Comment: Padraic, it appears there is an issue with what you provided in pastebin. It only outputs pairs, so when list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] and list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8], then it produces output like:
((1, 5), (1, 6))
((1, 7), (1, 8))

Comment: Yes, you need * len of the list http://pastebin.com/Bsjx4n6U

Comment: what should the output for `list1 = [1, 2, 3];list2 = [5, 6, 7]` be, almost all the answers  below return different output than your accepted answer so it is not clear what you actually want, the product or premutations

Comment: The output from that would be: [[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)], [(1, 5), (2, 7), (3, 6)], [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 7)], [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 5)], [(1, 7), (2, 5), (3, 6)], [(1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5)]]

I had the tuples inside coming out as lists in my original request, but that's not really import since I don't need them to be mutable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`repeat` the first list, `permutate` the second and `zip` it all together

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, repeat
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list(list(zip(r, p)) for (r, p) in zip(repeat(a), permutations(b)))
[[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)],
 [(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)],
 [(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]
```

**EDIT**: As Peter Otten noted, the inner `zip` and the `repeat` are superfluous.

```
[list(zip(a, p)) for p in permutations(b)]
```

Comment: It is not clear what it should do if the list are asymmetric. Does it work for you if `b` is the longer?

Comment: @AlexLenail I don't see any way to make any sense out of the problem description if the lists can be of different length. I just finished editing the question for clarity, in a way that bakes that assumption in.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer can be simplified to

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
[list(zip(a, p)) for p in permutations(b)]
```

(The list() call can be omitted in Python 2)

Answer (score 13):

As @pacholik s answer does not cover lists of different length, here is my solution, using a list comprehension with two variables:

```
first_list = [1, 2, 3]
second_list = ['a', 'b']

combinations = [(a,b) for a in first_list for b in second_list]
```

The output looks like this:

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
```

Comment: Which method is the fastest?  Like if you have a large list and big sample set. If say 40million combinations which method produces that the fastest?

Comment: Covers lists of different lengths but does something completely different. This just produces a product.

Comment: you are right, seems like I was too tired while reading the question...

Comment: Why did an answer that is *acknowledged to do something completely different* (and thus **not answer the question at all**) get 15 upvotes?

Answer (score 11):

Try to use list generator to create the nested lists:

```
>>> [[[x,y] for x in list1] for y in list2]
[[[1, 3], [2, 3]], [[1, 4], [2, 4]]]
>>>
```

Or, if you want one-line list, just delete brackets:

```
>>> [[x,y] for x in list1 for y in list2]
[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Comment: As I understand the question, this does not answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Edited my code to give you your desired output.

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
combined = []

for a in list1:
    new_list = []
    for b in list2:
        new_list.append([a, b])
    combined.append(new_list)

print combined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list by constructing all the permutations of two list members with this, containing the list combinations.

```
lst1 = [1,2]
lst2 = [3,4]

#lst = [[j,k] for j in lst1 for k in lst2] # [[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]
lst = [[[j,k] for j in lst1] for k in lst2] # [[[1,3],[2,3]],[[1,4],[2,4]]]
print lst
```

Comment: Padriac is right. That doesn't match what I'm looking for. It does match what itertools.product gives me, but isn't what I want.

Comment: I've revised mine below, I think it gives what you want now

Comment: This is functionally the same as Sdwdaw's answer, and inapplicable for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
combos=[]
for i in list1:
      for j in list2:
          combos.append([i,j])
print combos
```

Comment: Formatting tip: you can indent your code with 4 extra leading spaces to make it a neat code block like in the other answers.